# Demangling D Symbols when Profiling D Programs with perf

Tags: profiling, d, performance-testing, perf, demangler

I've just discovered the fantastic tool perf on Linux.

I profiled a D program with this but when I call

```
perf report
```

the symbols are not demangled.

I'm aware of `ddemangle` but this only works in batch-processing mode. I could always dump the output to a file for viewing. But it would be great if someone have found a solution to demangle the symbols *before* they are added to the perf database file.

Comment: I tried to get perf to work on my computer and it didn't want to.... but why doesn't perf report | ddemangle work? I think that should take care of the display demangling while still accepting input. If not maybe we can tweak it so it does.

Comment: I forgot that I could pipe things with `ddemangle`. It would be nice though to get demangling in interactive calls to perf aswell.

Comment: i did something silly... I wrote a terminal emulator back in October, including the ability to nest inside another terminal emulator. i just modified it to demangle all output on the fly. The code is here: https://github.com/adamdruppe/terminal-emulator also requires terminal, color, and eventloop from https://github.com/adamdruppe/misc-stuff-including-D-programming-language-web-stuff compile `dmd nestedterminalemulator.d terminalemulator.d arsd/terminal.d arsd/color.d arsd/eventloop.d -version=with_eventloop -version=d_demangle` then run `./nestedterminalemulator` and have some fun